# Downloading html code using beautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to learn some basic web scraping. What I am doing is downloading html code with beautifulSoup and I am printing results to cmd. The problem I have is when I open the site in chrome then I can see the data I want
[HTML code in chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XtJhS.png)

But when I download the code, then the body part looks like this [Downloaded HTML code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7h4FC.png)

I think that it might be some kind of safety measurement, but I am not sure.

I am **scraping** [this site](https://www.sreality.cz/hledani/prodej/byty/praha?velikost=1%2Bkk,1%2B1,2%2Bkk,2%2B1,3%2Bkk,3%2B1,4%2Bkk,4%2B1,5%2Bkk,5%2B1,6-a-vice,atypicky&stav=spatny-stav,pred-rekonstrukci,ve-vystavbe)

Appreciate your help.

Comment: The data is loaded via JavaScript dynamically. What information do you need to get from that site?

Answer (score 1):

BeautifulSoup can't see the elements you are trying to scrape, because they are being generated and populated asynchronously using JavaScript. This happens after your browser has made a request for- and received the base HTML for the page, which is a barebones sort of template to be populated later on, like I said, with JavaScript. BeautifulSoup only sees the barebones HTML.

So, you can't use BeautifulSoup. You could use Selenium, like others have said, but that isn't necessary. If you log your network traffic using Google Chrome's Developer tools (other browsers have a similar feature), you can see that your browser makes a request to a RESTful API, which serves JSON containing all the information you could ever want about each property. All you have to do is imitate that HTTP GET request:

```
def main():

    import requests

    url = "https://www.sreality.cz/api/cs/v2/estates"

    params = {
        "building_condition": "3%7C8%7C4",
        "category_main_cb": "1",
        "category_sub_cb": "2%7C3%7C4%7C5%7C6%7C7%7C8%7C9%7C10%7C11%7C12%7C16",
        "category_type_cb": "1",
        "locality_region_id": "10",
        "per_page": "20",
        "tms": "1592389441017"
    }

    response = requests.get(url, params=params)
    response.raise_for_status()

    estates = response.json()["_embedded"]["estates"]

    for estate in estates:
        print(f"GPS: {estate['gps']}")
        print(f"Name: {estate['name']}")
        print(f"Locality: {estate['locality']}")
        print(f"Price: {estate['price']}\n")

    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```

Output:

```
GPS: {'lat': 50.088512, 'lon': 14.399361}
Name: Prodej bytu 5+1 145 m²
Locality: Nerudova, Praha - Praha 1
Price: 1

GPS: {'lat': 50.028564, 'lon': 14.366739}
Name: Prodej bytu 2+kk 54 m²
Locality: Wassermannova, Praha - Hlubočepy
Price: 6651072

GPS: {'lat': 50.008667, 'lon': 14.466505}
Name: Prodej bytu 2+kk 45 m²
Locality: Na domovině, Praha 4 - Libuš
Price: 3899000

GPS: {'lat': 50.104355, 'lon': 14.585402}
Name: Prodej bytu 2+1 60 m²
Locality: Bryksova, Praha - Černý Most
Price: 5019000

GPS: {'lat': 50.028564, 'lon': 14.366739}
Name: Prodej bytu 4+kk 105 m²
Locality: Wassermannova, Praha - Hlubočepy
Price: 11467890

GPS: {'lat': 50.084553, 'lon': 14.417782}
Name: Prodej bytu 4+kk 229 m²
Locality: Praha 1 - Staré Město
Price: 29900000

GPS: {'lat': 50.042973, 'lon': 14.494473}
Name: Prodej bytu 1+kk 33 m²
Locality: Klapálkova, Praha 4 - Chodov
Price: 3350000

GPS: {'lat': 50.044209, 'lon': 14.496346}
Name: Prodej bytu 3+kk 205 m²
Locality: Milínská, Praha 10 - Záběhlice
Price: 8950000

GPS: {'lat': 50.042973, 'lon': 14.494473}
Name: Prodej bytu 1+kk 33 m²
Locality: Klapálkova, Praha 4 - Chodov
Price: 3350000

GPS: {'lat': 50.042973, 'lon': 14.494473}
Name: Prodej bytu 1+kk 33 m²
Locality: Klapálkova, Praha 4 - Chodov
Price: 3420000

GPS: {'lat': 50.070419, 'lon': 14.383278}
Name: Prodej bytu 3+kk 83 m²
Locality: Pod Radnicí, Praha 5 - Košíře
Price: 7800000

GPS: {'lat': 50.00695, 'lon': 14.416012}
Name: Prodej bytu atypické 191 m² (Podkrovní)
Locality: Československého exilu, Praha 4 - Modřany
Price: 1

GPS: {'lat': 50.028564, 'lon': 14.366739}
Name: Prodej bytu 5+kk 129 m²
Locality: Wassermannova, Praha - Hlubočepy
Price: 15706444

GPS: {'lat': 50.088615, 'lon': 14.469955}
Name: Prodej bytu 3+kk 96 m²
Locality: Jeseniova, Praha 3 - Žižkov
Price: 11500000

GPS: {'lat': 50.028564, 'lon': 14.366739}
Name: Prodej bytu 3+kk 67 m²
Locality: Wassermannova, Praha - Hlubočepy
Price: 7753995

GPS: {'lat': 50.11171, 'lon': 14.47769}
Name: Prodej bytu 2+kk 39 m²
Locality: Pod Labuťkou, Praha 8 - Libeň
Price: 3590000

GPS: {'lat': 50.126289, 'lon': 14.505613}
Name: Prodej bytu 2+kk 57 m²
Locality: Kytlická, Praha 9 - Prosek
Price: 1

GPS: {'lat': 50.057446, 'lon': 14.427087}
Name: Prodej bytu 2+kk 51 m²
Locality: Na Dolinách, Praha 4 - Podolí
Price: 3900000

GPS: {'lat': 50.016838, 'lon': 14.584877}
Name: Prodej bytu 3+kk 96 m²
Locality: K dálnici, Praha 10 - Pitkovice
Price: 8499000

GPS: {'lat': 50.028564, 'lon': 14.366739}
Name: Prodej bytu 5+kk 129 m²
Locality: Wassermannova, Praha - Hlubočepy
Price: 14942321

GPS: {'lat': 50.028564, 'lon': 14.366739}
Name: Prodej bytu 5+kk 131 m²
Locality: Wassermannova, Praha - Hlubočepy
Price: 14779177
```

You can change the `per_page` query string in the `params` dictionary to request more than 20 properties at a time. These query string parameters I also got just by looking at the request URL in the network traffic logger.

Comment: This is a great answer for this exact case! My answer regarding selenium is more general.

Comment: Thanks. It saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for you seeing what you see in the downloaded HTML code is that the site is actually a [progressive web app (PWA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_web_application). This means that the HTML is rendered from Javascript inside your browser, so it cannot be fetched with beautifulsoup.

There's a good news however. You just need to use a different tool, for example [Selenium](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/) browser automation. Once you fetched the rendered HTML with selenium you can proceed working with it using bs4 or any other tool.

What selenium does it takes a regular browser (called a webdriver), for example Chrome, Firefox or Safari, and automates it. Opens the page you want to scrape and renders the content, just like the regular browser does.

Once the content is rendered you can get the source HTML or even do more advanced things, like press buttons, log in etc.

Comment: great! I will try it

Answer (score 0):

Hello You can find this div tag using Class Name in Beautiful Soup

```
def match_class(target):
target = target.split()
def do_match(tag):
    try:
        classes = dict(tag.attrs)["class"]
    except KeyError:
        classes = ""
    classes = classes.split()
    return all(c in classes for c in target)
return do_match

html = """<div class="feeditemcontent cxfeeditemcontent">
<div class="feeditembodyandfooter">
<div class="feeditembody">
<span>The actual data is some where here</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>"""

from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

matches = soup.findAll(match_class("feeditemcontent cxfeeditemcontent"))
for m in matches:
    print m
    print "-"*10

matches = soup.findAll(match_class("feeditembody"))
for m in matches:
    print m
    print "-"*10
```